# Gmail search using regular expression on mail content

Tags: regex, email, gmail, wildcard

I wish to search in google in all my mails using a wildcard. however it seems gmail requires a regular expression to do this.

I wish to find all mails which contain a part of my string or more like:

```
inv*
```

should return:

> **inv**​ite
>   **inv**​oice
>   **inv**​ert
>   and so on..

Anyone has a suggestion in how I would be able to accomplish this?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2433

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
\binv\w*
```

This means

```
\b - start of a word
inv
\w = word character
* means 0 or more matches
```

If you use + it will mean it NEEDS one or more word characters after "inv"

```
\binv\w+
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but how do i apply this in gmail?

Comment: It isn't clear... you said: "however it seems gmail requires a regular expression to do this".  That made me think you knew where to use this.

Comment: You could look at this:  http://www.labnol.org/internet/advanced-gmail-search/21623/